# How to get minimal cover rects and get shortest path of this cover rects?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I have a shape that contains many small rectangles.I want use  fixed width and hegit rectangle cover the small rectangles, and I want use minimal cover rects that cover all small rectangles.And after that, I want get shortest path that from minimal cover rects center point goto another center point path.

**pseduo  code**

```py
import random

class Rect:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, w: float, h: float) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def contains(self, r: 'Rect') -> bool:
        if r.x < self.x or r.x + r.w > self.x + self.w:
            return False

        if r.y < self.y or r.y + r.h > self.y + self.h:
            return False

        return True

    def intersects(self, r: 'Rect') -> bool:
        if self.x > r.x + r.w or r.x > self.x + self.w:
            return False

        if self.y > r.y + r.h or r.y > self.y + self.h:
            return False

        return True

r1to5 = lambda : random.randint(1, 5)
r0to500 = lambda : random.randint(0, 500)

def generate_sample_rects():
    rects = []
    for _ in range(100):
        r1 = Rect(r0to500(), r0to500(), r1to5(), r1to5())

        # make sure rect no intersect each other.
        contian = False
        for r2 in rects:
            if r1.intersects(r2):
                contian = True
                break

        if contian:
            continue
        else:
            rects.append(r1)

    return rects


def minimal_cover_rects(w: float, h: float):
    minimal_rects = []  # list of Rect objects
    rects = generate_sample_rects()

    # here is how to calcs minimal rects ?

    return minimal_rects


def shortest_path(rects):
    shortest_path_rects = []

    return shortest_path_rects

minimal_rects = minimal_cover_rects(30, 30)
short_path = shortest_path(minimal_rects)
```

**minimal cover rects may like this**
the cover rectangle width and height maybe not fixed  so that can use best cover rectangle to cover samll rectangles. eg, cover width may be in a float range [10, 20], and cover height may be in a float range [15, 25].the cover rect width and height is
bigger some times than any samll rectangles.My pseduo code give a fixed width and height of cover rect.
[image]

**shortest path may like**
[image]

Hope good man can help me,my math and algorithm is poor.